# How to boot previous kernel in the RHEL/CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, rhel, boot

In some situations I would like to boot previous/older kernel. If I don't have access to the console, I can't select the kernel from the grub menu manually. What can I do in the RHEL/CENTOS 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose, it is possible to use `grubby`.

First get the list of available kernels:

```
# ls -l /boot/vmlinuz-*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 8913760 Sep 2 2020 /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue- 
27b1871295f04504829664d57efa8d65
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9485680 May 11 15:31 /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue- 
37e8e30f8707b94ff856f12c3dcc9e9f
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9514352 Nov 20 12:45 /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue- 
baccdb9816f313761ed13c744a89ebbc
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9485680 Feb 3 09:21 /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9485680 Mar 25 19:46 /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-240.22.1.el8_3.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9514352 Sep 23 2020 /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64
```

The system runs with the latest kernel `4.18.0-240.22.1.el8_3`. I want to boot the previous version `4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3`. To do so, I must pass the correct vmlinuz file as parameter of the `grubby --set-default` command:

```
# grubby --set-default /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64
```

and reboot the server.

After that I can for example uninstall the latest kernel (`4.18.0-240.22.1.el8_3` in this case) or do another thing, for which I rebooted to the older kernel version.